# Why does `subprocess.Popen` return a different output to the shell? - Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

If I run the following command from the `cmd.exe`, I get an error message that looks like so:

```
C:\Users\user>ctaags --help
'ctaags' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now if I run the same command using Python's `subprocess` module, I get a different warning:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['ctaags', '--help'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Based on other commands, I'd expect the output from `Popen` to exactly match what the shell gives me back, i.e.:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] 'ctaags' is not recognized as an internal or
external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This is not the case. Why?

Comment: Is there a reason there is a different number of a's in each `ctaa...aags`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syscall to run the process returns an error 2 regardless of whether it's called by the shell or from Python.

In the shell case, it's **the shell** that then generates the "not recognized" message.

Using `subprocess.Popen()` without `shell=True` (which you **should not** use without necessity), no shell is present, so you get the raw error code back yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Popen does not execute the command using the shell unless you set shell=True:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ctaaags', '--help'], shell=True)
```

Comment: ...but encouraging people to use `shell=True` is bad practice; in general, it introduces room for bugs, security-impacting and otherwise, as things intended to be program parameters can be (mis)interpreted by the shell.

Comment: don't use a list argument with `shell=True`. It does completely different thing on Unix. You don't need `shell=True` on Windows unless you want to a run a builtin command.